# How to validate client certificate in Azure APIM - Azure APIM Policy fails to validate certificate

Tags: c#, azure-api-management

I have written below c# code to call API in Azure APIM

```
    public async Task ValidateApimAsync()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = getX509Certificate2();
        try
        {              

            string baseAddress = // My base URL
            var requestHandler = new HttpClientHandler();   
  
            //attaching my client certificate, which is NOT NULL, 
            //retrieved from the windows cert store
            requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);  
            
            requestHandler.SslProtocols =  System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.None;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler))
            {                    
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync(string.Format("/echo/customerMessageIds"));
                responseTask.Wait();
                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                  
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have the below policy in APIM

```xml
<when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null)">
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="403" reason="Certificate is null" />
        <set-body template="none">Certificate is null</set-body>
    </return-response>
</when>
```

I have valid certificate, but still APIM returns response as "Certificate is null"

I am having windows 10 machine.

I even tried adding reg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

Value name: SendTrustedIssuerList Value type: REG_DWORD Value data: 0 (False)

but no luck

**UPDATE**

My code works when I use self signed certificate

It fails when I use the certificate which is created with the below configuration

```
 var key = RSA.Create();
 var publicParameters = key.ExportParameters(false);
```

it means I am requesting to export only the public key parameters of the RSA key pair. This means that the private key parameters, such as the private exponent, will not be included in the exported RSAParameters structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce it. How do get the certificate?

I had to some modifications:

- I created a certificate which is copied to the output directory
- I had to replace `_log`
- Information is displayed in the console window
- My API requires a subscription key, so I had to add it in the headers

```cs
public static async Task ValidateApimAsync()
{
    //X509Certificate2 certificate = getX509Certificate2();
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "secret");

    try
    {

        string baseAddress = "https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net";// My base URL
        var requestHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        //attaching my client certificate, which is NOT NULL, 
        //retrieved from the windows cert store
        requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        requestHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.None;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "secret");

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync(string.Format("/sample/certificate"));
            responseTask.Wait();
            var result = responseTask.Result;
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(result.ReasonPhrase);
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(ex.Message);
        //_log.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Certificate is null" />
                    <set-body template="none">Certificate is null</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                    <set-body template="none">Certificate was found</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: only difference is my certificate is not pfx.  It is .CER and signed by CA

Comment: I tried with se;lf signed certificate and it works!!  but CA signed certificate is not working!!

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question. But to answer your question, previous xml code only checks that a certificate is presented. It doesn't check that this cert/key is the one that you have uploaded to Azure APIM.

If your goal is to have a cert/key to be presented to your API, this is the `<choose>` code you should use:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Request.Certificate.Verify())">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```

This way, you also validate the presented certificate against the one you have stored in your certificate section in APIM.